# Why are new lines (CRLF) removed when a search-and-replace is performed?

Tags: notepad++, crlf

Regex - `:\s|,\s|,|\s|/|\\|\&|\$|"|%`
Also  tried `[:\s,\s,\s/\\\&\$"%]` with the same results.

I have marked replacement characters for a visual view to make sure.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this regex? Please add examples of text from before and how it should look after.

Comment: Regex above replaces illegal characters that cannot be used in a filename.  The list of characters above are being replace with and underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are replacing `\s` with nothing. `\s` stands for any kind of white space, including linebreaks.

If you want to replace only horizontal spaces (i.e. space, tab) use `\h`.

Comment: All these years, I never knew \s would replace \r\n in Notepadd ++  or that  a  \h could be used for a space     - make no sense for Regex but it works!  thank you!  Much appreciated.

Comment: found some info here.   https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/15279/unicode-blank-characters-and-the-regexes-h-v-and-s Thank you again Toto